# What does KEY SHARE OF in a PostgreSQL statement mean?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Given the following SQL, what does "ONLY", "OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=)" and "FOR KEY SHARE" do?

```
SELECT 1 
FROM ONLY "public"."acmeinstanceinfo" x 
WHERE "widgetid" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 
FOR KEY SHARE OF x
```

I have a fair amount of experience with Microsoft SQL server but zero with PostgreSQL. Any insights into what this query is doing would be great.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the effect of inserting or updating a row in a table that has a foreign key. See the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id integer PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE b (id integer REFERENCES a);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);
```

Now in one session, start a transaction and lock the row in `a`:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT id FROM a FOR UPDATE;

 id 
════
  1
(1 row)
```

Then, in another session, try to insert a row into `b`:

```
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1);  -- hangs!
```

What happened?

- The `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` took a `FOR UPDATE` lock on the row in `a`.
- The `INSERT` has to make sure that no concurrent transaction can delete the referenced row in `a` (or modify any of its key columns) to avoid inconsistencies.

  For that purpose, it runs

  ```
  SELECT 1
  FROM ONLY "public"."a" x 
  WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) 1 
  FOR KEY SHARE OF x;
  ```

  Here [`ONLY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) makes sure that no other tables are affected if `a` is part of an inheritance hierarchy, and `OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=)` is [PostgreSQL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-OPERATOR-CALLS) for a schema-qualified operator (since operators are also subject to `search_path`, PostgreSQL has to make sure that the correct `=` operator is used).
- Since `FOR UPDATE` and `FOR KEY SHARE` locks conflict (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ROW-LOCK-COMPATIBILITY)), the second session is blocked.

You can avoid that block by using `SELECT ... FOR NO KEY UPDATE` instead of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  The latter is only needed if you plan to update a primary or unique key column or if you intend to delete the row.

Comment: What if it's generated as part of delete query, and you are sure that there are no records referencing the records you're trying to delete?

Comment: @Dragas If *what* is generated as part of a `DELETE` statement?

Comment: The `select 1 from table x where ... for key share of x` query is being run in the background whenever I am trying to delete records from the table that is being referenced by the fk constraint. Since FK constraint is `on delete restrict` my process is to clean up the referring table first only to later clean the referred table in the same transaction, but postgres still seems to wait for the mentioned locking query to resolve first.

Comment: @Dragas Well, PostgreSQL has to run the internal trigger query to make sure that there are no referencing rows, right? If you already deleted all referencing rows in the same transaction, that query cannot block.